# TweetSharp - Unable to load posts

Tags: tweetsharp

we were using `TweetSharp 6.0.2.0` to pull the twitter posts and displaying them on the website.

But suddenly it started displaying this:

```py
"Unable to load posts".
```

TweetSharp is not returning any post details. Also there is no error message.

Please, suggest me some steps to find the issue, thank you.

Comment: We were using "ListTweetsOnUserTimeline" method and it is not throwing any exceptions.